Teradata SQL workday function?
In Excel I can do WORKDAY Function like this =WORKDAY("2024/11/15";15)
How if applied to SQL TERADATA? or is there a way to display the date 15 days in the future by excluding Weekend ?
I have tried this method but it includes weekends, I want to exclude weekends and only display the total weekdays for the next 15 days
SELECT CURRENT_DATE+15
Thanks

What about holidays?

If you literally only want to exclude weekends, you can use the built-in calendar view (sys_calendar.calendar):
with cte as (
select
c.*,
row_number() over (order by day_of_calendar) as rn
from
sys_calendar.calendar c
where day_of_week not in (1,7)  --exclude sat/sun
)
select
*
from
cte
where
rn between (select rn from cte where calendar_date = current_date) and (select rn + 15 from cte where calendar_date = current_date);

Teradata also has a set of macros and other calendar tables that you can customize, allowing you to define business days, etc.
https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_VMware/SQL-Date-and-Time-Functions-and-Expressions/Business-Calendars/Business-Calendar-Macros
